# Invalid arguments: No host specified in URL file:///Trousers

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm new to flutter.
The image from the URL is not being displayed on the screen.
The error is that No host in the specified URL. And I am currently learning from a tutorial but the instructor's code works well and mine does not. Please do help me as I am new to this.

Here is my `Main.dart` file:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyShop',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ProductsOverviewScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

products_overview_screen.dart

```dart
 class ProductsOverviewScreen extends StatelessWidget { 
  final List<Product> loadedProducts = [ 
    Product(
      id: 'p1', 
      title: 'Red Shirt', 
      description: 'A red shirt - it is pretty red!', 
      price: 29.99, 
      imageUrl: 
          'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg', 
    ),
    Product( `
      id: 'p2', 
      title: 'Trousers',
      description: 'A nice pair of trousers.', 
      price: 59.99, 
      imageUrl:
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg/512px-Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg',
    ), 
    Product( 
      id: 'p3', 
      title: 'Yellow Scarf', 
      description: 'Warm and cozy - exactly what you need for the winter.', 
      price: 19.99, 
      imageUrl: 
          'https://live.staticflickr.com/4043/4438260868_cc79b3369d_z.jpg', 
    ), 
    Product(
      id: 'p4',
      title: 'A Pan',
      description: 'Prepare any meal you want.',
      price: 49.99, 
      imageUrl: 
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg/1024px-Cast-Iron- Pan.jpg',
    ), 
  ];

  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    return Scaffold( 
      appBar: AppBar( 
        title: Text('My Shop'),
      ),
      body: GridView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        itemCount: loadedProducts.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ProductItem(
          loadedProducts[i].id,
          loadedProducts[i].title,
          loadedProducts[i].imageUrl,
        ),
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is `Product_item.dart`

````
class ProductItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String imageUrl;
ProductItem(this.id, this.imageUrl, this.title);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridTile(
      child: Image.network(
        //imageUrl
        imageUrl,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    );
  }
} ```
````

This `product.dart`

````
class Product {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final String imageUrl;
  bool isFavorite;

  Product({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.description,
    @required this.imageUrl,
              this.isFavorite,
    @required this.price,
    @required this.title,
  });
} ```
````

Comment: Please add the code for `ProductItem` widget.

Comment: Where is your `Product` class

Comment: Again edited and added

Comment: Thank you so much !!! This worked and I understood the mistake. I appreciate the help. I dont have the privilege to upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `ProductItem` class. You have not assigned the item the way they are defined numerically.

> Like: `ProcutItem(this.id, this.title, this.imageUrl)`, the item should also be passed in that same manner. No changes in that

**SOLUTION**

```
class ProductItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String imageUrl;
  ProductItem(this.id, this.title, this.imageUrl);  // <---- Here is the change
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridTile(
      child: Image.network(
        //imageUrl
        imageUrl,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Since, you have passed the item in this way in your `ProductOverViewScreen`

```
        // first should be id, then title, then imageURl. It should match from the above class
        ProductItem(
          loadedProducts[i].id,  
          loadedProducts[i].title,
          loadedProducts[i].imageUrl,
        )
```

**ASSUMPTIONS**

My `Product` class looks like this, I am sure you might have made the class in this way only. Your `Product` class is not available in the code, hence, the assumptions. You can refer to this code, if you want

```
class Product{
  double price;
  String id, title, description, imageUrl;
  
  Product({this.price, this.id, this.title, this.description, this.imageUrl});
}
```

**RESULT**

[image: Result Screenshot]